# JSON Formatting a List Column - Two colors for two situations

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a Modern SharePoint list with a Review Date column. I'm trying to configure JSON so that if the entry has Today's Date, it will highlight Red.  If it is between today and 15 days from now, it will highlight Yellow.

I'm just not sure how to write those conditions together, and include the 15 days syntax. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this JSON code in SharePoint [column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) for your date column:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": "black",
        "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, '', if(toLocaleDateString(@currentField) == toLocaleDateString(@now), 'red', if(@now < @currentField && @currentField <= addDays(@now, 15), 'yellow', '')))"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you!!